# Why and how SQL condition not in psql explain plan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I try to analyze plans for join query benchmark https://github.com/gregrahn/join-order-benchmark

For example, I execute the following command:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM aka_name AS an,
     cast_info AS ci,
     company_name AS cn,
     keyword AS k,
     movie_companies AS mc,
     movie_keyword AS mk,
     name AS n,
     title AS t
WHERE an.person_id = n.id
  AND n.id = ci.person_id
  AND ci.movie_id = t.id
  AND t.id = mk.movie_id
  AND mk.keyword_id = k.id
  AND t.id = mc.movie_id
  AND mc.company_id = cn.id
  AND an.person_id = ci.person_id
  AND ci.movie_id = mc.movie_id
  AND ci.movie_id = mk.movie_id
  AND mc.movie_id = mk.movie_id;
```

and as a result, I got the following query plan

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                                 [0/1803]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=1973375.70..22192463.47 rows=22337517790 width=449)
   Hash Cond: (ci.movie_id = t.id)
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=102.03..2617413.84 rows=88800840 width=203)
         Merge Cond: (n.id = an.person_id)
         ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.87..2341713.60 rows=36244344 width=130)
               Merge Cond: (ci.person_id = n.id)
               ->  Index Scan using person_id_cast_info on cast_info ci  (cost=0.44..1714393.60 rows=36244344 width=56)
               ->  Index Scan using name_pkey on name n  (cost=0.43..163847.25 rows=4167379 width=74)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.42..69770.80 rows=901343 width=73)
               ->  Index Scan using person_id_aka_name on aka_name an  (cost=0.42..67517.44 rows=901343 width=73)
   ->  Hash  (cost=834975.33..834975.33 rows=24906348 width=246)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=486218.85..834975.33 rows=24906348 width=246)
               Hash Cond: (mk.movie_id = t.id)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=4885.82..131552.82 rows=4523930 width=37)
                     Hash Cond: (mk.keyword_id = k.id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on movie_keyword mk  (cost=0.00..69693.30 rows=4523930 width=12)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=2290.70..2290.70 rows=134170 width=25)
                           ->  Seq Scan on keyword k  (cost=0.00..2290.70 rows=134170 width=25)
               ->  Hash  (cost=372278.91..372278.91 rows=2609129 width=209)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=141184.56..372278.91 rows=2609129 width=209)
                           Hash Cond: (mc.movie_id = t.id)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=11266.43..106748.81 rows=2609129 width=115)
                                 Hash Cond: (mc.company_id = cn.id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on movie_companies mc  (cost=0.00..44881.29 rows=2609129 width=40)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=5344.97..5344.97 rows=234997 width=75)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on company_name cn  (cost=0.00..5344.97 rows=234997 width=75)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=61280.28..61280.28 rows=2528228 width=94)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on title t  (cost=0.00..61280.28 rows=2528228 width=94)
 JIT:
```

as you can see, condition `mc.movie_id = mk.movie_id` not present in this plan. How and why it possible?

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this query from the benchmark. The idea of this benchmark is comparing internal optimizer of different databases. That is why this query in FROM\WHERE format.

Comment: Are there still databases that do *not* support standard compliant joins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the last 3 conditions:

```
AND ci.movie_id = mc.movie_id
AND ci.movie_id = mk.movie_id
AND mc.movie_id = mk.movie_id;
```

Using `movie_id`, you are matching table `ci` with `mc`, then `ci` with `mk` which therefore implies that `mc` matches `mk`, and therefore the last condition is superfluous and the planner rightfully ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

JGH answered this.

This isn't an answer, but this is the proper way to write joins (the INNER isn't strictly necessary but I prefer explicit). FROM table1,table2 WHERE ... is a bad habit you should break immediately. That syntax is not very flexible and can make even simple queries near impossible to read.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM aka_name AS an
 INNER
  JOIN NAME AS n
    ON an.person_id = n.id
 INNER
  JOIN cast_info AS ci
    ON an.person_id = ci.person_id
   AND n.id = ci.person_id
 INNER
  JOIN title AS T
    ON ci.movie_id = t.id
 INNER
  JOIN movie_keyword AS mk
    ON t.id = mk.movie_id
   AND ci.movie_id = mk.movie_id
 INNER
  JOIN movie_companies AS mc
    ON t.id = movie_companies.movie_id
   AND ci.movie_id = mc.movie_id
   AND mc.movie_id = mk.movie_id
 INNER
  JOIN keyword AS K
    ON mk.keyword_id = k.id
 INNER
  JOIN company_name cn
    ON mc.mc.company_id = cn.id;
```